# Password reset will not let me type

Tags: password-recovery

I tried doing the password reset but when I went to enter in the new password it would not let me type. I went into the root section, entered `passwd` and then my user-name, and it went into the area where it allows you to reset it but it would not let me type. I tried multiple times still with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for some password feedback as you will get in windows like dots ( . ) or astersik ( *) symbols then, you don't get here. but no problem you can just type the password what you want and then continue.

No need to wait for that.it will automatically be recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Linux terminals by default do not show anything when you enter the password. This is considered a security feature where it becomes difficult for someone looking at your screen to know how long and what your password is.
You might even type a backspace in your password fooling someone into thinking that your password is say 10 characters long, whereas its actually 8 characters.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this is a security feature.

However, you can set Ubuntu to show a `*` character when you type a password.

Execute the following:

```
sudo EDITOR=nano visudo
```

Change the line:

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

To:

```
Defaults        env_reset,pwfeedback
```

To save changes and exit, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.